# Deleting from table based upon the result set of other query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-delete, correlated-subquery

I am trying to delete data from a table by looking up on the result set which is returned by correlated sub-query. My queries are as below.

```
select DISTINCT M24no,M0no
from V_SRC_I_FIN_ENGMNT_STG E
```

The above query will return a table result-set as below.

```
M24no M0no
2546  2570
```

Now I need to delete all the records from I_IPV_LOB_PROG_PROV_MO_MTRC_TRNS table which has MO_IDS between M24no and M0no.

I am trying to do something like this as below but it seems to be incorrect. Can somebody suggest me an amicable solution?

```
DELETE
FROM I_IPV_LOB_PROG_PROV_MO_MTRC_TRNS
WHERE LST_UPD_USERID='FINANCE'
AND MO_ID IN 
(select DISTINCT M24no,M0no
from V_SRC_I_FIN_ENGMNT_STG E)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished using an `INNER JOIN` to the `V_SRC_I_FIN_ENGMNT_STG` table and the `BETWEEN` clause:

```
DELETE  A
  FROM  I_IPV_LOB_PROG_PROV_MO_MTRC_TRNS A
    INNER JOIN V_SRC_I_FIN_ENGMNT_STG B ON A.MO_ID BETWEEN B.M24no AND B.M0no
  WHERE LST_UPD_USERID = 'FINANCE'
```

So effectively you delete everything from table `A` (`I_IPV_LOB_PROG_PROV_MO_MTRC_TRNS`) that is joined to `B` (`V_SRC_I_FIN_ENGMNT_STG`) where `MO_ID` is between `M24no` and `M0no`.

Comment: This worked well.But I changed the second table to cut down the execution time. Your query runs for ever.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `exists`:

```
DELETE FROM I_IPV_LOB_PROG_PROV_MO_MTRC_TRNS
WHERE LST_UPD_USERID ='FINANCE' AND
      EXISTS (select 1
              from V_SRC_I_FIN_ENGMNT_STG E
              where MO_ID bewteen M24No and M0no
             );
```